# Existence of a minimal ideal with a specific property

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, supersymmetry, super-algebra

Suppose that $R$ is a super-commutative ring (i.e. it is a unital $\mathbb{Z}_2$-graded ring satisfying $xy=(-1)^{|x|\cdot |y|}yx$ where $|x|$ denotes the grading degree of a homogeneous element $x\in R$), $J_R\subset R$ is the ideal of $R$ generated by $R_1$ i.e. $J_R=RR_1$. Consider the set $\Gamma$ of all ideals $I\subset R$ such that $J_R+I\subset R$ is a maximal ideal of $R$. It is clear that $\Gamma$ is not empty (any maximal ideal containing $J_A$ belongs to $\Gamma$).

My question is, is it always the case that $\Gamma$ contains a minimal element? in other words, if $\{I_i\}_{i\in X}$ is a collection of ideals satisfying this property (i.e. $J_R+I_i$ is a maximal ideal for every $i\in X$), does it follow that the intersection $\cap_{i\in X} I_i$ is such that $\cap_{i\in X}I_i+J_R$ is a maximal ideal?

If not, are there any conditions on $R$ (or $J_R$) that ensures that this holds?

The motivation for my question relates to the following question:

Given a super-commutative ring $R$, a super-ideal $I$ of $R$ (i.e. an ideal which is homogeneous), can we construct a bigger ideal $J$ containing $I$ such that $R/I$ is a superfield (a superfield is a super-commutative ring $F$ such that $\overline{F}:=F/J_FF$ is a field) in a minimal manner? of course, one can always take $J$ to be a maximal ideal containing $I$, and the quotient $R/J$ would be a field, not just a superfield. However, I am interested in the case where the resulting superfield is as minimal as possible i.e. constructed to kill the odd part (i.e. those of grading equal to 1) in a minimal way.

If fact, answering my first question in a positive way settles my motivation positively as well by Zornification-type of argument.